# Mejorar este script (linting). Function statements should not be placed in blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery

primero pido disculpa si la pregunta es muy tonta ya que no manejo mucho del tema.
Estoy realizando este script y lo testee con lint javascript me arrojo 2 warning que podria mejorar

> 1 Unnecessary 'else' after disruption.
>       } else {
>
> 2 Function statements should not be placed in blocks.Use a function expression or move the statement to the top of the outer function.

Como podría corregir esos errores o por lo menos el segundo.
Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

```js
 var productMainCategoryId = $('#productMainCategoryId').val();


if (productMainCategoryId == 23 || productMainCategoryId == 27 || productMainCategoryId == 28) {
    $("small.float-xs-right").text('Limite 20 caracteres');

    function validar() {
        //Almacenamos los valores
        nombre = $('.product-message').val();

        //Comprobamos la longitud de caracteres
        if (nombre.length < 20) {
            alert('La formula funciono. texto agregado');
            return true;

        } else {
            $("small.float-xs-right").html("<span style='color: #ff0000;'>Se excede el limite permitido</span>");
            alert('La formula funciono, pero te pasaste de los caracteres');

            return false;
        }

    }

} else if (productMainCategoryId == 29 || productMainCategoryId == 30 || productMainCategoryId == 31) {
    $("small.float-xs-right").text('Limite 18 caracteres');

    function validar() {
        //Almacenamos los valores
        nombre = $('.product-message').val();

        //Comprobamos la longitud de caracteres
        if (nombre.length < 18) {
            alert('La formula funciono con 18. texto agregado');
            return true;

        } else {
            $("small.float-xs-right").html("<span style='color: #ff0000;'>Se excede el limite permitido</span>");
            alert('La formula funciono, pero te pasaste de los caracteres');

            return false;
        }

    }
} else if (productMainCategoryId == 26) {
    $("small.float-xs-right").text('Limite 18 caracteres');

    function validar() {
        //Almacenamos los valores
        nombre = $('.product-message').val();

        //Comprobamos la longitud de caracteres
        if (nombre.length < 25) {
            alert('La formula funciono con 25. texto agregado');
            return true;

        } else {
            $("small.float-xs-right").html("<span style='color: #ff0000;'>Se excede el limite permitido</span>");
            alert('La formula funciono, pero te pasaste de los caracteres');

            return false;
        }

    }
} else if (productMainCategoryId == 24) { //Classic II 15 carac
    $("small.float-xs-right").text('Limite 18 caracteres');

    function validar() {
        //Almacenamos los valores
        nombre = $('.product-message').val();

        //Comprobamos la longitud de caracteres
        if (nombre.length < 15) {
            alert('La formula funciono con 15. texto agregado');
            return true;

        } else {
            $("small.float-xs-right").html("<span style='color: #ff0000;'>Se excede el limite permitido</span>");
            alert('La formula funciono, pero te pasaste de los caracteres');

            return false;
        }

    }
} else {
    alert('El Id de la página actual es diferente al ID del la formula');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="" onSubmit="return validar();">
 <div>
  <label> Marcado</label>
  <p></p>
  <input type="hidden" id="productMainCategoryId" value="29">
  <textarea placeholder="marca aca" class="product-message" maxlength="250"  name="marcado"></textarea><br>
  <small class="float-xs-right">Máximo 200 caracteres</small>
  <p></p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary float-xs-right" type="submit" name="submitCustomizedData">guardar</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

Edit, Saque la función del condicional

```
var productMainCategoryId = $('#productMainCategoryId').val();

function validar() {
        //Almacenamos los valores
        limiteCaracter = $('.product-message').val();


if (productMainCategoryId == 23 || productMainCategoryId == 27 || productMainCategoryId == 28) {
    $("small.float-xs-right").text('Limite 20 caracteres');



        //Comprobamos la longitud de caracteres
        if (limiteCaracter.length < 20) {
            alert('La formula funciono. texto agregado');
            return true;

        } else {
            $("small.float-xs-right").html("<span style='color: #ff0000;'>Se excede el limite permitido</span>");
            alert('La formula funciono, pero te pasaste de los caracteres');

            return false;
        }

    } 
}
```

Codigo Nuevo

```js
var productMainCategoryId = $('#productMainCategoryId').val();

 function validar(largo, limite) {
  if (largo < limite) {
   alert('La formula funciono con ' + largo + '. texto agregado');
   return true;
    } 
     else
    {
  $("small.float-xs-right").html("<span style='color: #ff0000;'>Se excede el limite permitido</span>");
  alert('La formula funciono, pero te pasaste de los caracteres');
  return false;

  }
  }


 if ( productMainCategoryId == 23 
  || productMainCategoryId == 27 
  || productMainCategoryId == 28) {

  $("small.float-xs-right").text('Limite 20 caracteres');

  //Almacenamos los valores
    nombre = $('.product-message').val();

    validar(nombre.length, 20);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="" onSubmit="return validar();">
  <div>
    <label> Marcado</label>
    <p></p>
    <input type="hidden" id="productMainCategoryId" value="23">   <!-- El ID CAMBIA DEPENDENDO DE LA CATEGORIA-->
    <textarea placeholder="marca aca" class="product-message" maxlength="250"  name="marcado"></textarea>
    <br>
    <small class="float-xs-right">Máximo 200 caracteres</small>
    <p></p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary float-xs-right" type="submit" name="submitCustomizedData">guardar</button>
  </div>
</form>
<P> al abrir la página aparece un alert "La formula funciono con 0. texto agregado" y al poner 1 solo caracter y le doy guardar dice que me pase :( </P>
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1 Unnecessary 'else' after disruption. } else {

Indica que no hace falta un else si lo que sigue es la única opción disponible para retorno de la función.

```
fn C(){
  if (A) return TRUE
  else return FALSE
  /*** codigo aqui no llega a ejecutarse ***/
}
```

es lo mismo que

```
fn C(){
  is (A) return TRUE // 
  return FALSE; // retorna algo y cierra la función
}
```

> 2 Function statements should not be placed in blocks.Use a function expression or move the statement to the top of the outer function.

Indica que estás declarando o creando una función dentro de un bloque condicional:

```
if (A)
  fn C() { do B }
```

es mas optimizable de esta manera:

```
C = fn(){ do B }
if (A) C();
```

es decir sacas las funciones fuera del if

En el caso de tu código la función validar() es pasible de ser reescrita para ser un poco mas agnóstica o generalista. 
El resultado final será un código mas compacto y optimizable.

Por ejemplo:

```
function validar(largo, limite) {
  if (largo < limite) {
    alert('La formula funciono con ' + largo + '. texto agregado');
    return true;
  } 
  $("small.float-xs-right").html("<span style='color: #ff0000;'>Se excede el limite permitido</span>");
  alert('La formula funciono, pero te pasaste de los caracteres');
  return false;
}
```

y luego la llamas así (2 opciones, la primera almacena el valor del mensaje y pasa el length la segunda lo pasa directo):

```
if ( productMainCategoryId == 23 || 
     productMainCategoryId == 27 || 
     productMainCategoryId == 28) {
  $("small.float-xs-right").text('Limite 20 caracteres');
  //Almacenamos los valores
  nombre = $('.product-message').val();
  validar(nombre.length, 20);

} else if ( productMainCategoryId == 29 || 
            productMainCategoryId == 30 || 
            productMainCategoryId == 31) {
  $("small.float-xs-right").text('Limite 18 caracteres');
  validar($('.product-message').val().length, 18);
 //...
```

y así

Comment: Amigo, gracias por tu respuesta en cuanto al punto dos llevo horas tratando de sacar la función del if, la saque y funciona pero el codigo '$("small.float-xs-right").text('Limite 20 caracteres');' no me aparece al cargar la página. otro punto es que la función es un codigo re utilizable yo la tengo repetida 4 veces. por fa podrias instruirme como hacerla mas limpia yo te lo agradezco llevo horas en esto :( arriba edite lo que hice

Comment: al refactorizar tenes que ir viendo que cosas se repiten y que cosas se pueden abstraer, una segunda vuelta de refactorización puede llegar a ser pasarle el div donde mostrar el mensaje `$("small.float-xs-right")` como un tercer parametro asi lo podes usar en otros lados

Comment: Malbarez, realmente ya tengo vergüenza escribirte hize lo que me dijiste pero no se que pasa, al cargar la página aparece un alert _La formula funciono con 0. texto agregado_ y si pongo 1 caracter cuando el limite son 20 p ej dice que me pase. que estoy haciendo mal? arriba subí el codigo de lo que hago, te doy las gracias y te pido disculpa por esto